# In GCP, how to route Custom Domain for Cloud Run to Load Balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I setup a cloud run app, I have brought a custom domain, I would like to add load balancer to it.

How do I change the custom domain DNS to point to the new load balancer IP?  I have tested the IP and it works.

My working load balancer IP (example only):

```
1.2.3.4:80
```

My working external custom domain (example only):

```
dev.mywebsite.com
```

Here is what I have tried, I just pasted the IP into the CNAME record and it doesn't work.  It say the website could not be reached.

[image]

Comment: 1) Do you really need a load balancer for Cloud Run? 2) This link provides details:  https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless

Comment: Yes, there are other considerations

Comment: You cannot simply create a DNS CNAME for Cloud Run.  Edit your question to include details on the load balancer and Cloud Run configuration.

Comment: Well the load balancer and cloud run already work, they can be accessed individually, I just need to re-route DNS to use the load balancer IP, which is what I need help with.  When I just copy the load balancer ip to the CNAME, it doesn't work.  Do you know how to re-route the DNS to load balancer?

Comment: The fact that they work independently does not mean they will work together with your configuration. Cloud Run has a proxy in front of it handling traffic. The hostname must match what you configured in the Cloud Run service. Provide the details requested so that you can get an informed answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Load Balancer in front of Cloud Run you have to [define a serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts). There is special things for custom domain in the backend service section.